# Router to Router Setup, using Crossover or Standard?

Tags: networking

I have a network with DHCP from the `WirelessRouter`.

```
----<WirelessRouter/Router>----<-100meters->----<?ANOTHER ROUTER?>-----to other computers
|
|
|
|
----Connected to other computers
```

For the 100 meters, I use copper wire. Do I need to use a crossover setup for RJ45? Or can I just use the standard setup of RJ45?

Here in my house, I already set up the 100 meters with a standard setup, in which if we remove the `<?ANOTHER ROUTER?>`, the 100 meters will connect directly to one computer only.

I want to add some routers there, but my instructor said that a standard setup of RJ45 will not work for router-to-router here.

Maybe I missed something above, I forgot what a crossover setup or a standard setup is. I assume that crossover is for router-to-router or a computer-to-computer connection. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "Newer routers, hubs and switches (including some 10/100, and all 1 Gigabit or 10 Gigabit devices in practice) use auto-MDIX to automatically switch to the proper configuration once a cable is connected." [Auto-MDIX wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_dependent_interface#Auto-MDIX)

Answer (score 2):

Just remember simple rule:

when the devices are same, then crossover cable is used.

when devices are different, Straight cable is used.

so for router-to-router we need crossover cable.

Comment: Does it matter on which port is use to connect router and which port is use to connect PC?

Comment: usually not. only,when there is VLAN setup

Answer (score 0):

This is special thing which is against standard rule to connect router to router we should use straight through cable let me elder to get the answer why this is use but its confirmed straight through is used

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.